# Form input fields don't respond to being clicked

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

So, we have a .net 5.0 wpf application which on startup loads a window containing a cef browser. The browser then loads our login form. The application is running on win 10 64 bit machines exclusively. This has worked without a problem for the past 6 months. Yesterday i installed the application on one of our customers' laptops. The installation went down without a hitch, but after the cef browser loaded the login form I was unable to interact with the input fields. By that I mean that if I put my cursor above the text field my cursor changes shape, but upon clicking no cursor would appear inside the text field and anything I typed wouldn't appear in the text filed. Clicking the Login button didn't have the expected effect of telling me that I am missing username and password, instead it moved the trigger areas of all input elements downward while they were still being rendered at the same position as before.

This problem is exclusive to this one machine. All other machines running the application aren't experiencing and never have experienced anything like this so i'm not expecting it to be a bug within cefsharp.

My question is if anyone has had a similar issue or any idea how to workaround it.

CefSharp version being used is 94.4.110.

Comment: Does the laptop have an Intel 11th Gen iris graphics card? If yes you need to upgrade the graphics card driver see https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000058136/graphics/graphics-for-11th-generation-intel-processors.html

Comment: How about upgrading to WebView2 ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Upgrading to WebView2 as Dean suggested, solved the issue and also some minor gripes I've had with CefSharp.